How to set "Re-run" option in GitHub for a failed Jenkins Job
In the below image with GitHub actions, can see "Re-run jobs" option is present.
I want to create the same Re-runs option using Jenkins.

I have tried all possible options in Jenkins with different plugins.
Can someone point me right steps?
Thanks in advance.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/rebuild/ maybe? Or without plugins, https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/running-pipelines/#restarting-or-rerunning-a-pipeline?

Thanks for checking, but I was looking for an "Re-run" option on the GitHub PR page.
